# How to clean users associated with SSH Metadata on GCE instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Does anyone know how to clean  users associated with SSH Metadata on GCE instances? Not sure I am asking the question correctly/clearly. Interestingly, I could use `gcloud compute ssh` login as any user which never existed before. After login as any non-existing user, next time this user will be added to any new VM. Because of a typo, I have some users I don't want to have when a new instance is created.

Comment: "*I have some users I don't want to have when a new instance is created*" => do you mean that you want to restrict SSH access to the VM to only some users? If so, you can control who can access the VM by granting `roles/compute.osLogin` to only a subset of your users (read https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users). You can bind `roles/compute.osLogin` role to some users directly on the project (inherited to all VMs) or on a single VM.

Comment: I don't think so. I feel like OSlogin allows a user to login as any user with the same SSH key. GCP will create anyone not exist yet. I want to clear them. I think they may saved in metadata somewhere.

Comment: A new VM is created without users on it (if an opposite is not specified by your customizations). A new user leaves trail only after the first login. "After login as any non-existing user, next time this user will be added to any new VM." - could you provide more evidences of this, i.e. steps to reproduce?

Comment: @mebius99: I use `gcloud compute ssh` without OS Login. By default: gcloud compute ssh ensures that the user's public SSH key is present in the project's metadata. If the user does not have a public SSH key, one is generated using ssh-keygen(1). See the doc of the command: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `gcloud compute ssh` ensures that the user's public SSH key is present in the project's metadata. If the user does not have a public SSH key, one is generated using ssh-keygen(1). See the command's documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh).

So this convenience sometimes creates inconvenience as I have experienced. To remove unwanted user names and ssh keys from project's metedata, use `gcloud compute project-info add-metadata --metadata-from-file` to overwrite metadata. Detail see official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys).

This is not relevant to ssh with OS Login configured.